# How to display saved date on the update\delete dialog in fullcalendar 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have this code in default.aspx:

```
<td class="alignLeft">
    <input type="datetime-local" id="eventStart" name="startdaytime" runat="server">               
</td>
```

I want to display the saved date, while opening the dialog.

```
function updateEvent(event, element) {
    // alert(event.description);

    if ($(this).data("qtip")) $(this).qtip("destroy");

    currentUpdateEvent = event;

    $('#updatedialog').dialog('open');
    $("#eventName").val(event.title);
    $("#eventDesc").val(event.description);
    $("#eventId").val(event.id);
    $("#eventStart").val(event.start);
    //moment($("#eventStart").val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm");
    //new Date($("#eventStart").text(event.start));
    
    $("#colorPicker").val(event.color);
    $("#EditEventNote").val(event.note);
    

    if (event.end === null) {
        $("#eventEnd").text("");
    }
    else {
          $("#eventEnd").val(event.end);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have tried in many ways, but nothing is working.

Update:call to the 'UpdateEvent':

```
 $('#updatedialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 680,
            buttons: {
                "update": function () {
                    var eventToUpdate = {
                        id: currentUpdateEvent.id,
                        title: $("#eventName").val(),
                        description: $("#eventDesc").val(),
                        color: $("#colorPicker").val(),
                        start: new Date($("#eventStart").val()),
                        end: new Date($("#eventEnd").val()),
                        note: $("#EditEventNote").val(),
                    };
                   PageMethods.UpdateEvent(eventToUpdate, updateSuccess);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                     },
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Update n.2

```
 currentUpdateEvent.title = $("#eventName").val();
                currentUpdateEvent.description = $("#eventDesc").val();
                currentUpdateEvent.color = $("#colorPicker").val();
                currentUpdateEvent.note = $("#EditEventNote").val();
                currentUpdateEvent.start = new Date($("#eventStart").val());
                currentUpdateEvent.end = new Date($("#eventEnd").val());
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',currentUpdateEvent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the event dates are delivered to as momentJS objects from fullCalendar, you should be able to format the date to the required format using momentJS's [format() function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

As per the [documentation for a datetime-local field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local), an example of the required format is `2017-06-01T08:30`, so this means you should be able to write

```
$("#eventStart").val(event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss"));
```

for the start field, and similar for the end field.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, but unfortunately I keep seeing the input boxes not valued.

Comment: Hm, strange. Can you show how the `updateEvent` function is being called, please?

Comment: But that calls PageMethods.UpdateEvent which is provided by ASP.NET ... it doesn't call the `updateEvent()` function you showed us originally.

Comment: Thanks for your second edit. However that code is calling the updateEvent function provided by fullCalendar. It's not calling **your** updateEvent function

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand, you mean the c # method call?

Comment: No. In the question originally you showed a JavaScript function called `updateEvent` which looks like it opens a dialog and populates some fields. You said it wasn't working to display the dates. Whilst your code to display the date wasn't correct, now I'm wondering whether you're actually even calling that function at all. Instead you've shown me calls to two other unrelated functions in 3rd-party libraries. It's not a difficult question - how and where do you call your `updateEvent()` function?

Comment: Sorry ADyson, the only other call I find to updateEvent is the following: eventClick: updateEvent,

Comment: That'll be it, then, thanks. Let me think why it might be not working fully and get back to you.

Comment: Apologies, the format string should be slightly different. For me it was putting a warning in the browser's Console - did you see anything like that? It needed to be a `[T]` instead of `T` so the T is treated as literal text rather than a formatting character, otherwise it seems to print A or P for that (for AM or PM). I have updated the answer above, and also here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGRBQgV